# Testing component extending two other components in Angular / Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have three components that are extending each other TileComponent -> CollectionElementComponent -> SelectableItemComponent. Now, I am trying to write some unit tests for the TileComponent class using Jasmine 3.4.0 and Angular 8. However, the test (should create component) fails, because the mocked selectableService is not properly injected in the extended extended component:

```
Failed: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
    at TileComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/shared/components/selectable/selectable-item.component.ts:26:14)
    at TileComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/collection/view/elements/collection-element/collection-element.component.ts:32:15)
    at TileComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/collection/view/elements/tile/tile.component.ts:65:15)
```

With `selectable-item.component.ts:26:14` referring to this call (also see the code snippet further down): `this.selectableService.onDeselectAllSelectedItems.pipe(...)`

I init the testing component like this:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                TileComponent,
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: SelectableService, useClass: MockSelectableService },
            ],
            schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
        })
            .compileComponents()
            .then(() => {
                fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TileComponent);
                component = fixture.componentInstance;
                fixture.detectChanges();
            });
    }));

it('should create component', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});


  ...

@Injectable()
class MockSelectableService {
    onDeselectAllSelectedItems = new EventEmitter<void>();
}
```

This way of injecting the service into the component worked for other component tests, so I am not entirely sure why it fails here. I have tried pretty much everything already, using `ng-mocks` and `MockComponent()` in the declarations for the two parent components, trying to mock both parents and injecting them using `{ provide: ComponentName, useClass: MockComponentName}`. Also tried to override the ngOnInit methods using `component.ngOnInit = () => {}` in the beforeEach method or `CollectionElementComponent.prototype.ngOnInit = () => {}` etc. All of them result in the same error.

The affected components look like this:

```
export class SelectableItemComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor(
          public selectableService: SelectableService
      ) { }

      ngOnInit() {
          this.selectableService.onDeselectAllSelectedItems
              .pipe(takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$))
              .subscribe(this.deselectItem.bind(this));
      }
}
```

This class is extended by the CollectionElementComponent:

```
export class CollectionElementComponent extends SelectableItemComponent implements OnInit {
          constructor(
             public selectableService: SelectableService,
          ) {
             super(selectableService);
          }

          ngOnInit() {
             super.ngOnInit();
             // some other stuff
          }
}
```

And last, the TileComponent extending the CollectionElementComponent

```
export class TileComponent extends CollectionElementComponent implements OnInit {
              constructor(
                 public selectableService: SelectableService,
              ) {
                 super(selectableService);
              }

              ngOnInit() {
                 super.ngOnInit();
                 // some other stuff
              }
    }
```

Any help or tips are highly appreciated, since I am really out of ideas... 
Thanks for the support!

Comment: The error indicates that `onDeselectAllSelectedItems` is undefined. This means that `selectableService` **is** defined and depedency injection seems to work. Does `MockSelectableService` have a property `onDeselectAllSelectedItems`?

Comment: thanks @rveerd. yes, the `MockSelectableService` does have the property `onDeselectAllSelectedItems` (see code above). I copied it from the original `SelectableService`, so it should be exactly the same.

Comment: Have tried debugging the tests to see what `this.selectableService` is and what properties it has?

Comment: couldn't really get the debugging to run properly, but that's another issue. Luckily, the problem sort of resolved itself now, I have no idea why. Rebooted VSCode and now it works. thanks for the support anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [ng-mocks](https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks) you could use [MockBuilder](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockBuilder) or [MockProvider](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockProvider) too:

```js
beforeEach(() => MockBuilder(
  TileComponent,
  [
    CollectionElementComponent,
    SelectableItemComponent,
    SelectableService,
  ],
));

it('test', () => {
  // mocking the prop of SelectableService 
  const selectedItems$ = new EventEmitter();
  MockInstance(
    SelectableService,
    'onDeselectAllSelectedItems',
    selectedItems$,
  );

  const fixture = MockRender(TileComponent);
  // should work properly now
});
```